# jenkins pipeline post condition consistently entering the changed condition unless SUCCESS

Tags: jenkins, conditional-statements, jenkins-pipeline

Running Jenkins ver. 2.89.2

Take the declarative pipeline.

```groovy
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('init') {
      steps {
        script {
          currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
          //currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
          //currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
          //currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
        }
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    always {
      echo "Always: $currentBuild.currentResult vs $currentBuild.result"
    }
    changed {
      echo "Changed: $currentBuild.currentResult vs $currentBuild.result"
    }
    success {
      echo "Success: $currentBuild.currentResult vs $currentBuild.result"
    }
    unstable {
      echo "Unstable: $currentBuild.currentResult vs $currentBuild.result"
    }
    failure {
      echo "Failure: $currentBuild.currentResult vs $currentBuild.result"
    }
    aborted {
      echo "Aborted: $currentBuild.currentResult vs $currentBuild.result"
    }
  }
}
```

Running with SUCCESS multiple times gives an output of (does not enter the change block on subsequent runs):

```
[Pipeline] echo
Always: SUCCESS vs SUCCESS
[Pipeline] echo
Success: SUCCESS vs SUCCESS
```

However, the `change` block is always entered when running with any other state (UNSTABLE, FAILURE, etc)

```
[Pipeline] echo
Always: UNSTABLE vs UNSTABLE
[Pipeline] echo
Changed: UNSTABLE vs UNSTABLE
[Pipeline] echo
Unstable: UNSTABLE vs UNSTABLE
```

I would expect the first "changed" status to enter the change block, but not the subsequent ones. This works with the SUCCESS result. Why not the other result states?

Comment: Sounds like [JENKINS-48752](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48752)

Comment: Thanks @mkobit - you are right. Embarrassing that I didn't find it myself ;-)  I'll answer the question to close it.

Answer (score 0):

As @mkobit rightly answered, this is covered with [JENKINS-48752](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48752). Thanks again.